# How to install the latest IPython notebook in Ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: 12.04, software-installation, python, ipython

The solution in this question on Stack Overflow, [Unable to open an existing notebook in IPython Notebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16496687/unable-to-open-an-existing-notebook-in-ipython-notebook), advises installing the latest notebook, but I was unable to find how to do so.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Found it. Here's how:

```
sudo pip install --upgrade ipython[all]
```

It then complains about missing jinja2.

```
sudo pip install jinja2
```

Comment: I would recommend doing `pip install --user` instead, so you don't have to pollute the site's installation. It's just safer.

Comment: For me, `sudo pip install jupyter` was missing.